# Delete MouseOver Effect on custom Combobox style wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox, mouseover, styling

In my wpf document I have made a custom Combobox style like so:

```
<ComboBox Background="#222222" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Width="250">
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#262626" />
</ComboBox.Resources>
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers> <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"> <Setter Property="Background" Value="#262626" /> </Trigger> </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ComboBoxItem Foreground="White" Name="Item1">Item1

</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem Foreground="White" Name="Item2">Item2</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem Foreground="White" Name="Item3">Item3</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem Foreground="White" Name="Item4">Item4</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem Foreground="White" Name="Item5">Item5</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem Foreground="White" Name="Item6">Item6</ComboBoxItem>
```

But whenever I hover over one of the ComboboxItems, I still get the default hover colour, so how do I remove it and place my colour?

I am relatively new to coding so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the default `ControlTemplate` of the `ComboBoxItem` in order to override the default visual state triggers.
Check [Microsoft Docs: Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframework-4.8#in-this-section) to see the default `Style` implementation of framework controls.

**ComboBoxItem `Style`**

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
              <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" 
                       Value="True"> 
                <Setter Property="Background" 
                        Value="#262626" /> 
              </Trigger> 
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      <Setter>
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```